# Resources won't load if not logged to cPanel after migration, cause?

Tags: accessibility

I migrated my wordpress site to my live site. As mentioned in the title my site will look bad if I visit it and I am ot logged in cPanel. Guess it means resources are not accessable to all users. How to make site resources accessable to all?

Comment: what do you mean by "looks bad", do you have any errors in your logs?  did you check with a debugger (ie f12) to see if something is missing?  There could be LOTS of things wrong here...

Comment: Try opening opening the [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) in your browser (like in Chrome). In the "Console" tab it should provide more details regarding which resources are not loading.

Comment: @rudtek I mean that things like the logo, the fonts, and scripts won't load, unless I am logged into the cpanel, therefore the root of the error must be on the accessibility to the resource urls, which are not accessible to anonymous (non-logged) users at this point...

Comment: do you have ssh access?

Comment: @rudtek Nope I don't, do I need it?

Comment: it would be easier to change the permissions of the files if you had ssh.  what is the url?

Comment: @rudtek alight i can use ssh access, and here's the urls that won't load https://imgur.com/a/4Tl3v, the site's http://pendragonsbay.com

Comment: @Stephanie Here's the resources that aren't loading: https://imgur.com/a/4Tl3v

Comment: is all your site actually live?  Are you still using localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some of your assets are using `http://localhost/...` links instead of your domain which is why they aren't loading.  These might be hardcoded in your theme or you may want to check your `options` table in the database for `option_name` "siteurl" and "home" and make sure they are updated to use the right URL instead of `http://localhost`

Comment: It's also a good idea to use a database migration or site migration plugin when you move from localhost to a live site. They handle a lot of search-and-replace cases that manually changing won't.

Comment: Yup I had home set as localhost still, and I also recommend step seven o this guide for anyone with this error http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/.